# Site Loads to the Right, until finished, then centers

Tags: javascript, html, css

There were 2 other threads on Stackoverflow of people having this issue.  Neither applied to me. One was something about javascript. I disabled javascript on my browser, still did this.

The other was adsense banners, and I don't have any on this page.

Can someone give me an idea why this is loading to the right, and then centering when the page is fully loaded?

Thanks!

http://www.halotracker.com/Reach/TrueSkillLB.aspx?GameType=Competitive&Playlist=13

Comment: CBRacer got me started, but left me hanging. Still need help.

Comment: There are over 3000 errors with the HTML on your site. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.halotracker.com%2FReach%2FTrueSkillLB.aspx%3FGameType%3DCompetitive%26Playlist%3D13&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 fixing these may go a long way towards fixing your problem. And even if it doesn't, finding the error will be a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, I looked at your link and there is definitely some ugliness that could be fixed up. But 90% of it is things like alt in images and stuff like that.  Thanks though, I'll pay more attention to this.

Comment: I was missind a </td> tag on my tables, and since there were a ton of rows, it made a ton of errors in the validator. Fixed the tag, but this didn't fix my problem

Answer (score 8):

It's because your width on the tables is set to 100% with two of the columns with the * to determine the padding.  the * character tells the table to determine the width remaining and fill it with the table.  So what happens is the browser renders the first * less the fixed width of the center column.  It doesn't even render the third column until after the centering occurs.  You can see this with firebug and stop the load when it is still aligned to the right.

```
<div class="SiteBody">
 <table width="100%">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td width="*"></td>
    <td width="1062"></td>
    <td width="*"></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

I will say this once because so many will probably jump on this.  You shouldn't use Tables to setup layout it's bad practice and it can give you problems like what you are seeing.  That said, my conscience is clear.

You could remove the the first and third TD's, remove the Width 100% and set the background in the parent container. In my opinion this would be the best way to handle it.  Set the margin to 0, auto and that should give you everything you are wanting.

```
<div class="SiteBody">
 <div class="SiteMiddle">//site content</div>
</div>

<style>
 .SiteBody { background: transparent url(image of background) }
 .SiteMiddle { width:1062px; margin: 0, auto; }
</style>
```

OR  This is probably the best way as it layers the divs and allows you to set the backgrounds for left and right and still set a centered content with the correct width

```
<div class="SiteBody">
 <div class="SiteLeft">
  <div class="SiteRight">
   <div class="SiteMiddle">//site content</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<style>
 .SiteBody {  }
 .SiteLeft { background: transparent url(image of left background) no-repeat left top; }
 .SiteRight { background: transparent url(image of left background) no-repeat right top; }
 .SiteMiddle { margin: 0, auto; width: 1062px; }
</style>
```

Comment: The left and right td are auto because their backgrounds are overly large to compensate for people with very wide screens.  So if your resolution is not wide, all you will basically see is the main site.  How would I accomplish the same task without a table?

Comment: @bladefist also just a tip unless you are using going to reference the class multiple times on the same page it should probable be an ID.  Not that this makes any difference in the code, just a best practice. (class = multiple calls on the same page, ID = one call per page)

Comment: Getting close. The left/right div's underlap the middle div, in order to make the images all fit on the screen.  The left/right div's need to sit against the center, not go behind it (images arent lining up right)

Comment: I removed the banner to show you http://gyazo.com/62b8210b9bfa61020c6c1cebe3597327

Comment: I don't typically agree with this type of coding and there may be a better way to do it.  but what comes to mind initially is to set a relative position on the .SiteBody class set a fixed position on the siteleft and siteright classes.  give the site body a fixed width the same as your middle content, and then position the fixed elements outside of the SiteBody (siteleft left: -468px, sightright right: 470px;) something like that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4236/discussion-between-cbrracer-and-bladefist)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use tables for layout.

They cause the page to be rendered more slowly, and may cause very late adjustments. I'm sure you've noticed this ;)

The site design doesn't look very complex. I would advise you to remake it without the use of tables as layout (the tables for the playlists are fine of course).

Comment: I've done this, starting with CBRRacer's comments. Have been unable to reproduce it with DIVs

Comment: You know what I mean. I cannot get the site to line up properly with DIVs

Answer (score 1):

Hm, it's difficult to say, but this may be because of the right box with "position:absolute"

Maybe you should get rid of the table centering your main content, so as not to confuse your browser about the positon of every element on the page.

Try this one for HTML:

```
<div class="SiteBody">
<!-- remove table stuff here -->
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Your content -->
  </div>
<!-- remove table stuff here -->
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.SiteBody {text-align:center;}
.container {width:1062px;margin:0 auto;text-align:left;position:relative;}
```

Comment: I still need a way to show the left and right side images, with them being aligned towards the center

Comment: Where are you seeing the position absolute?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's Cufon - which replaces your fonts after the dom is loaded. Can you replace Cufon and see if you still have this issue?

If that doesn't can you put up a test version of your page with all the script tags removed?

Comment: http://www.halotracker.com/Test/Halo%20%20Reach%20Challenges.htm   No script, no absolute divs, no cufon.  Still acting weird. Thanks for your help

Comment: @bladefist that one doesn't change from align right to align center for me; it is centered from the start. Although the columns don't work properly. Could it be some sort of reflow issue caused by how much HTML is being server?

Comment: @bladefist that one works fine for me too on FF and chrome. Which browser are you seeing the reflow issue with?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use TABLES for layouts. If you use TABLES, use fixed width cells.
2. Move JS script tag to the end of HTML code.
3. Try to disable one by one the JS scripts and see what's happening.
4. Monitor your HTML rendering in real-time with Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

After analysis of your site, below are my comments:-

1. Page total weight is of **2736.6 Kbytes** (Which is high)
2. CSSImages weight is **986 Kbytes**
3. JS files weight is **623.2 Kbytes**
4. If you can use caching on server for **CSS** & **JS** files then page load will reduce
5. As **CBRRacer** mentioned, you should handle that too

Answer (score 0):

I stripped all the javascript, cufon, absolute divs, etc from the site here

http://www.halotracker.com/Test/Halo%20%20Reach%20Challenges.htm

The only thing left is the tables. And I've seen the tables work before. I've always used tables and this problem randomly started. Anyway, cant figure it out, none of the answers given to me were complete.

Enjoy my reputation points CBRacer.